# Reading special characters from FoxPro using OLEDB

Tags: ado.net, oledb, dbf, .net

I'm using the FoxPro OLEDB driver (VFPOLEDB.1) to connect to a DBF using ADO.NET. The problem I am having is that some characters don't come across correctly. For example the '²' character comes out as '_'.

I have tried issuing the SET ANSI OFF command, to no avail.

I have found that the DBF is codepage 850

Does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I had to add `CodePage=850` to the connection string so that it matched the DBF's code page.

Answer (score 1):

Foxpro doesn't support UNICODE if that is what you appear to be getting.  It only works with ASCII 0-255 character set.  Codepage 850 I believe is MS-DOS.  There is a CPConvert() (for code page conversion), but I don't know if that is associated with the OleDbProvider as a usable function.